# How to connect to gRPC C++ InProcessChannel not from C++?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, grpc-c++

I'm [trying](https://github.com/4ntoine/JniBenchmarking/tree/master/rpc) gRPC as JNI alternative and the idea is to have gRPC service on C++ side and client connected on Java/Android side. In order to have the best possible performance i'd prefer to use in-process channel (open to your suggestions).

How can i connect to C++ gRPC server with [`InProcessChannel()`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/946ed32bac27c49a559c4ae7e9f059c5e31a161a/include/grpcpp/server.h#L107)? The problem is that i need to [pass](https://github.com/4ntoine/JniBenchmarking/blob/3e775c28cfa57824131d2e75baaa1774e86faf46/rpc/src/androidTest/java/com/eyeo/ctu/rpc/AndroidRpcTest.kt#L85) a `name` for Java's `InProcessServerBuilder`.

In C++ gRPC tests (eg. [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/946ed32bac27c49a559c4ae7e9f059c5e31a161a/test/cpp/end2end/message_allocator_end2end_test.cc#L166)) i can't find it's set and it makes me think `InProcessChannel` can be used in pure C++ only (both server and client are in C++). Is it still possible for C++ service and Java client?

PS. I was able to do it for Java-server + Java-client.

PPS. I've found a couple of similar QnAs [eg. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600158/is-it-possible-to-use-java-client-to-call-c-server-in-the-same-process-using-i) but i wonder if there is still a way to make it working together (probably with some 3rd-party channel impl). Can it work over Unix Domain Sockets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ and Java "in-process" transports weren't named appropriately for cases multiple languages are in the same process. The in-process transports only work within each individual language; the C++ and Java in-process transports can't interact.

You should use the normal HTTP/2 client/server.

While something like you want could exist, as maybe a "shared memory" transport, it is a significant amount of work and would see relatively little usage for the maintenance burden.

Comment: It seems that Unix Domain Socket should work. It's reportedly [supported by gRPC C++](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/md_doc_naming.html) and should be doable in Java according to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54189910/1103561). Right? The current problem is that Android shared libs is required and `netty-transport-native-epoll` isn't ready for Android afaik

Comment: "normal HTTP/2 client/server" is ~ 100x slower (`Socket` compared to `InProcess`)

Comment: Netty is poorly optimized for Android and while it may work gRPC doesn't officially support it as we don't think it would live up to our expectations. I wouldn't normally recommend trying to get netty-transport-native-epoll working on Android (but it seems you did!). Android has LocalSocket, which requires an adapter before being passed to OkHttpChannelBuilder.socketFactory(). May be a bit annoying, but that's the path I'd normally recommend trying for UDS.

Comment: `InProcess` in Java is very fast in part because it doesn't need to serialize the protobuf messages and it can make some short-cuts with multi-threading. Both of those optimizations are only available for Java-to-Java RPCs. So its current performance is not indicative of the performance you'd see of a "cross-language in-process transport." We'd expect only a modest speed improvement of such a transport, mainly related to 1-2 fewer `memcpy()`s.

Comment: i will try `OkHttpChannelBuilder.socketFactory()`

Comment: I've [implemented it](https://github.com/4ntoine/JniBenchmarking/commit/fcbd6aaf6306e0acbf5a0ead8f175218c8b32dbf) using `.socketFactory()` though it looks strange. Any better way to pass unix socket path (i did it in a very weird way - directly to SocketFactory). Any performance suggestions overall?

Comment: I think passing the unix socket path directly to the `SocketFactory` is appropriate at this time. Yes, it is weird. I do have ideas on how we could improve that by adding support directly in gRPC, but for the moment the hack is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I've accepted Eric's Anderson answer as correct. However it might be useful to know how i made it [working](https://github.com/4ntoine/JniBenchmarking/blob/a056d4030fc0d9841c48d62f6209b2ca773a18d5/rpc/src/androidTest/java/com/eyeo/ctu/rpc/AndroidRpcTest.kt#L166) with Unix Domain Sockets.

I had to [patch](https://github.com/4ntoine/netty/tree/epoll-android) `netty` for Android and [use it](https://github.com/4ntoine/JniBenchmarking/blob/a056d4030fc0d9841c48d62f6209b2ca773a18d5/rpc/build.gradle#L105). Pay your attention to some Android-specific permission [notes](https://github.com/4ntoine/JniBenchmarking/blob/a056d4030fc0d9841c48d62f6209b2ca773a18d5/rpc/src/androidTest/java/com/eyeo/ctu/rpc/AndroidRpcTest.kt#L89).